# Can I break my Pi in a way that can't be fixed with a new SD card?

Tags: safety

Aside from physical damage (treading on it), is there anything that I could do to the Pi that could irreversibly damage it?

More specifically, will anything I can do with code, or by prematurely taking out the SD card (I know this can corrupt the SD card), damage the Pi?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a quote from Gert.

> Do NOT experiment with trying to guess registers in that area.
>   Especially if you start 'playing' with, or accidentally hit a power register
>   you have the small, but distinct possibility of blowing up your PI.

http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=8496&p=101319

So, apparently, yes, there is the possibility of activating a power register and frying the RPI.

Comment: That sounds like fun!

Answer (score 10):

You could [overclock the RPi](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt#Overclocking_configuration) through `over_voltage`. Overclocking it through `arm_freq` and `gpu_freq` is supported, but `over_voltage` can damage the CPU and will void your warranty. You do this through your [config.txt](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt). Here is a [related question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-are-the-overclocking-capabilities) that gives a bit more information on overclocking and its dangers.

Comment: Related: [What are the overclocking capabilities?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-are-the-overclocking-capabilities).

Comment: @Jivings Thanks for that related question! I'll add the link to my answer.

Comment: Voiding your warranty is not the same as breaking the device (though of course it is possible to break it by overvoltage.)

Comment: @finnw I don't see how "over_voltage can damage the CPU" is not breaking the device.