# How to overclock raspberry pi 3 without overvoltage

Tags: pi-3

I want to speed up the image processing and one idea that comes to my mind is overclocking but I only have 5v supply and 2A limitation on my psu can I overclock my Pi 3 withou overvoltage or overcurrent?

Comment: What OS are you running on your Pi?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the overclocking capabilities?](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72/what-are-the-overclocking-capabilities), specifically [this answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/19625/33476).

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev your answer is outdated what about raspi 3 i saw that the question was asked and answered 4 years ago. what about raspberry pi 3. i went to raspi-config and the overclocking section is not applicable

Comment: @wayne That answer doesn't even mention `raspi-config`. **Read it**. [This blog](http://www.jackenhack.com/raspberry-pi-3-overclocking/) specifically states that `arm_freq` parameter still works for RPi 3.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily overclock your Raspberry Pi 3 but please keep in mind that with great power comes great responsibility.

There is [an article here from the RetroPie git repo](https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/Overclocking) which tells you all about the instructions and information about overclocking.

You can try it out by modifying the overclock settings in config.txt. But please stay within the limits mentioned by the link above: we're not responsible for any damage caused by this. You would probably want to edit the values for GPU and CPU.

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Please also note that there are some settings which flip a hardware switch inside the Pi and void the warranty, these are:

- over_voltage greater than 6
- force_turbo=1
- temp_limit greater than 85

Answer (score 1):

Open the terminal and type `sudo nano /boot/config.txt`.

Find: `#arm_freq=800`, delete the `#` and change `800` to whatever speed you want with a max of `1400`, but that is not recommended.

This is what mine looks like: `arm_freq=1300`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you for the info :) are you using pi 3??